# How to retrieve or read comments of particular column in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have added some comments for column

```
 COMMENT ON COLUMN STUDENT.STUDENT_NAME
 IS 'This is comment for the column';

 COMMENT on column student.student_name 'THIS IS COMMENT FOR THE COLUMN' succeeded.
```

How can I view it using query?

Comment: Do you need to return everything from your database, otherwhise you just do select * from rack;

Comment: Which dbms? (Not all products have information_schema support...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you are using `ORACLE` RDBMS. In that case, you can use `user_col_comments` system view:

```
SELECT comments
FROM user_col_comments
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'STUDENT' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'STUDENT_NAME'
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b54b5/2)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
select * from user_tab_comments where table_name='STUDENT'
```

or this:

```
select * from all_tab_comments where table_name='STUDENT'
```

Comment: Its giving me Empty result. although comments are present.

Comment: Do you get empty results from all_tab_comments  as well ?

Comment: @learner: table names are stored in upper-case in Oracle. Try `where table_name='RACK'`